# How to Enable/Disable Adobe PDF Reader Active X Internet Explorer Browser Ext VIA Registry?

Tags: internet-explorer, registry, adobe

I'm unable to find the reg setting to enable or disable Adobe PDF Reader IE Active X browser extension. I am trying to avoid having to manually change this for 30 users.

I used LOG-MD to compare the before/after of the registry after changing the add-in from enabled to disabled.

Open IE > Tools > Manage add-ons > Toolbars and Extensions > Show: All add-ons > Adobe PDF Reader

Manually enabling/disabling works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to disable the Adobe PDF add on using Group Policy instead of Registry setting.

When you set the group policy, it will create a proper registry key by itself.

You can refer steps below may help you to enable/ disable add on using group policy.

(1) Get the CLSID for the add-on you want to enable or disable:

A. Open IE, click Tools, and then click Manage Add-ons.

B. Double-click the add-on you want to change.

C. In the More Information dialog, click Copy and then click Close.

D. Open Notepad and paste the information for the add-on.

E. On the Manage Add-ons windows, click Close.

F. On the Internet Options dialog, click Close and then close IE.

[image]

(2) From the copied information, select and copy just the Class ID value.

> Note:-
>
> You want to copy the curly brackets as well as the CLSID:
>   {47833539-D0C5-4125-9FA8-0819E2EAAC93}.

(3) Open the Group Policy Management Editor and go to:

> Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows
>   Components\Internet Explorer\Security Features\Add-on Management.

-OR-

Open the Local Group Policy Editor and go to:

> User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows
>   Components\Internet Explorer\Security Features\Add-on Management.

(4) Open the Add-on List Group Policy Object, select Enabled, and then click Show.
The Show Contents dialog appears.

(5) In Value Name, paste the Class ID for your add-on, for example, {47833539-D0C5-4125-9FA8-0819E2EAAC93}.

(6) In Value, enter one of the following:

> 0= The add-on is disabled and your employees can’t change it.
>
> 1= The add-on is enabled and your employees can’t change it.
>
> 2= The add-on is enabled and your employees can change it.

(7) Close the Show Contents dialog.

Reference:

[Using the CLSID and Administrative Templates to manage group policy objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/enable-and-disable-add-ons-using-administrative-templates-and-group-policy#using-the-clsid-and-administrative-templates-to-manage-group-policy-objects)

If you still want the solution using Registry key than you can refer steps below.

(1) Get the Class ID from IE > Tools  > Manage  Add-ons

(2) Create Registry key on location below.

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Ext\Settings{47833539-D0C5-4125-9FA8-0819E2EAAC93}]
>   “Flags”=dword:00000001
>
> Note: 0 is for enable and 1 is for disable.

Reference:

[Disable Particular IE add-on via registry](https://smulpuru.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/disable-particular-ie-add-on-via-registry/)

Comment: Thanks @Deepak-MSFT, I'll try this.